# How to execute msbuild /t:updateuid for all projects in a solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, build, localization, msbuild

is there an easy way to execute `msbuild /t:updateuid <project file>` for all projects in a solution?

I have a huge solution with more than 150 projects and want to set Uids to all *.xaml files in all projects in the solution. I don't want to add this line to every project, but execute it from one place. Thus I can easilly control the execution of the command. 
For example during the development phase I would like to disable the command to make the build process faster and just before the test phase i would like to enable it from one place. Any suggestions are wellcomed.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my problem using the information on the [this](http://blog.seravy.com/solution-wide-msbuild-target/) blog.
The idea is to inject a custom `.targets` file, which will be processed by **msbuild** for every project. Imagine we have the following solution structure:

- SolutionFolder

  - MySolution.sln
  - after.MySolution.sln.targets
  - UpdateAutomationIds.targets

The `after.MySolution.sln.targets` file will be processed by the msbuild. It will inject our `UpdateAutomationIds.targets` file to be executed for every project in the solution. Just replace *MySolution* with the name of your solution.

**after.MySolution.sln.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets>$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)</CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <SolutionPath>$(SolutionPath);CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets=$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)UpdateAutomationIds.targets</SolutionPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**UpdateAutomationIds.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="UpdateAutomationIds" Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)'=='.csproj'" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Updates automation ids. Project: $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Importance="high"/>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildToolsPath)\msbuild.exe&quot; /t:updateuid &quot;$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)&quot;"/>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildToolsPath)\msbuild.exe&quot; /t:checkuid &quot;$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)&quot;"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```